# Путь файла в TextBox1

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Привет Всем!

Есть форма c button1 и TextBox1, как сделать на нажатие кнопки открытие openfiledialog1 и выбор файла, а в textbox1 показ пути к нему?

```
private:System::Void button1_Click(System::Object ^ sender, System::EventArgs ^ e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
    openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    openFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Это код открытия openfiledialog1.

Answer (score 1):

У `OpenFileDialog` есть свойство `FileName`. Значение этого свойства после вызова `ShowDialog` надо присвоить свойству `Text` нужного текстового поля.